# Finding smallest value in python

Tags: python, numerical-methods

I am looking for some help with creating a code for the following in python

[image]

I have made an attempt at an answer but I am not quite sure how to finish it. Here is what I have so far

```
import numpy as np
import math
from numpy import cos
x=10**(-p)
funct = (1-math.cos(x))/x
```

So I have defined my function that I am trying to calculate, I believe I did that correctly with

```
funct = (1-math.cos(x))/x
```

I have said what x needs to be with

```
x=10**(-p)
```

But how do I add the code to find the smallest value of p which has no correct significant digit at x = 10**-p when using standard double precision?

Do I need to somehow use

```
print(min(funct))
```

Looking for some help with this execution, thanks!

Edit: new code

```
import numpy as np
import math
for p in range(10): 
    x=10.0**-p; 
    result = (1-np.cos(x))/x
    print (p)
    print (result)
    Test = 2*np.sin(x/2)**2/x
    print (p)
    print(Test)
```

gives the results:

```
0
0.459697694132
0
0.459697694132
1
0.0499583472197
1
0.0499583472197
2
0.00499995833347
2
0.00499995833347
3
0.000499999958326
3
0.000499999958333
4
4.99999996961e-05
4
4.99999999583e-05
5
5.0000004137e-06
5
4.99999999996e-06
6
5.00044450291e-07
6
5e-07
7
4.99600361081e-08
7
5e-08
8
0.0
8
5e-09
9
0.0
9
5e-10
```

Comment: You are far off. Python is not math - `=` operator is assignment in python, to define functions you need the `def` keyword, etc. In other words, you have to **learn python first**, before trying to use it. You can't write python code with math knowledge alone. You need to read a python tutorial.

Comment: @nosklo okay thanks for the advice, just trying to learn python for the first time now

Comment: I suggest reading the official python tutorial. The book "Think Python" is also good and free in the internet.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Comment: okay i see how to use functions but how do i find the smallest value of p?

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the loop

```
for p in range(15): x=10.0**-p; print p, x, (1-np.cos(x))/x, 2*np.sin(x/2)**2/x
```

I get the values for the expression and a theoretically equivalent expression

```
p   x       (1-cos(x))/x       2*sin²(x/2)/x

0  1.0    0.459697694132     0.459697694132
1  0.1    0.0499583472197    0.0499583472197
2  0.01   0.00499995833347   0.00499995833347
3  0.001  0.000499999958326  0.000499999958333
4  0.0001 4.99999996961e-05  4.99999999583e-05
5  1e-05  5.0000004137e-06   4.99999999996e-06
6  1e-06  5.00044450291e-07  5e-07
7  1e-07  4.99600361081e-08  5e-08
8  1e-08  0.0                5e-09
9  1e-09  0.0                5e-10
10 1e-10  0.0                5e-11
11 1e-11  0.0                5e-12
12 1e-12  0.0                5e-13
13 1e-13  0.0                5e-14
14 1e-14  0.0                5e-15
```

but I have no idea how to interpret the task to give a valid answer. Could be p=5 or could be p=8.

Comment: why did you use sin? to get the equivalent answer?

Comment: and how could i edit this into my code to get your output?

Comment: from that i see that it would be p=5 since it has no correct sig fig

Comment: how could i edit that into my code? then i can accept the answer, thanks btw!

Comment: Use trigonometric theorems, `cos(2x)=cos²(x)-sin²(x)=2*cos²(x)-1=1-2*sin²(x)`. The only thing that should be changed is to replace the package alias `np` by the full name `numpy` or in this case you can also use the `math` functions.

Comment: i just made an edit to my original post trying to figure that result table out, could you fix my edit? ill accept your answer now

Comment: There is nothing to fix, you computed the necessary values. You could research the facilities python has for formatted output, either in the printf version or the newer one.

Comment: I am trying to line it up like you have it done but i cant seem to get it correctly